# Distributing application on customer's account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios-provisioning

I developed an application using my account and made the AppStore developer AdHoc distribution to the client. Once received the customer's approval, he asked me to put the application through his business.

I have to do the same process I did in my account, creating a certificate, distribution provisioning, or the same file that I generated with my account I can rise to his account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new developer certificate for yourself through your clients apple dev account, and use that certificate to sign the app when you build for distribution. Also, the bundle ID for the app needs to be created in his account, be sure to set that correctly in the project.